# dnsmasq reading /etc/hosts, but not using it

Tags: linux, hosts-file, dnsmasq

I've done a default install of dnsmasq.  When I run dig, it seems to be using dnsmasq (127.0.0.1), but the results don't include the hostnames included in /etc/hosts.

/etc/hosts:

```
192.168.1.13 sun
```

in a terminal:

```
$ dig sun

; <<>> DiG 9.6-ESV-R4 <<>> sun
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 32131
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;sun.               IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.           9699    IN  SOA a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2011041100 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Apr 12 05:20:56 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 96
```

in a terminal:

```
$ dig @localhost sun

; <<>> DiG 9.6-ESV-R4 <<>> @localhost sun
; (2 servers found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
    ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 43763
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;sun.               IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.           10800   IN  SOA a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2011041800 1800 900 604800 86400

;; Query time: 40 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Mon Apr 18 17:15:23 2011
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 96
```

I've tried using local and expand-hosts/domain, but can't seem to get either of those working either.  My primary goal is to be able to use one machine to host LAN DNS, I don't care if the names wind up being sun or sun.domain, whatever works.

Here is my /etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
domain members.linode.com
search members.linode.com
nameserver 72.14.188.5
nameserver 72.14.179.5
```

and /etc/dnsmasq.conf

```
domain-needed
bogus-priv
```

This is all on an ubuntu 10.04 machine if it makes a difference.  I have been following this guide: [http://www.mythicalbeast.co.uk/linux/dnsmasq_howto.html](https://web.archive.org/web/20111229020603/http://www.mythicalbeast.co.uk:80/linux/dnsmasq_howto.html) (though not verbatim since that also sets up DHCP)

Comment: Are you sure the option 'no-hosts' isn't being passed to dnsmasq somehow? What is the result of 'dig @localhost sun'.

Comment: added the result of 'dig @localhost sun'.  I double-checked /etc/dnsmasq.conf and confirmed that no-hosts was commented out.  Is there some other way that option could be getting set?

Answer (score 8):

I know this is from 2011, but since it still has no accepted answer:

Today, I had a similar problem. Curl worked to get the expected response from a haproxy lxc with the respective header, but somehow my local dnsmasq did not provide resolution for `container.test` (confirmed with nslookup).

Google found me [this post](https://hugoheden.wordpress.com/2009/02/24/dnsmasq-and-etchosts/) by Hugo Heden, who said that is might be an issue with `/etc/hosts` formatting.

What solved the problem for me was:

1. Uncommenting `no-hosts` in `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`
2. Putting `123.123.123.12 container.test` into a new file, e.g. `/etc/dnsmasq.hosts`
3. Pointed dnsmasq to the new file by adding `addn-hosts=/etc/dnsmasq.hosts` to `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`

Answer (score 6):

This snippet from the [dnsmaq FAQ](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/FAQ) seems relevant:

> Q: Names on the internet are working fine, but looking up local names 
>      from /etc/hosts or DHCP doesn't seem to work.
>
> A: Resolver code sometime does strange things when given names without
>      any dots in. Win2k and WinXP may not use the DNS at all and just
>      try and look up the name using WINS. On unix look at "options ndots:"
>      in "man resolv.conf" for details on this topic. Testing lookups
>      using "nslookup" or "dig" will work, but then attempting to run
>      "ping" will get a lookup failure, appending a dot to the end of the
>      hostname  will fix things. (ie "ping myhost" fails, but "ping
>      myhost." works. The solution is to make sure that all your hosts
>      have a domain set ("domain" in resolv.conf, or set a domain in 
>      your DHCP server, see below fr Windows XP and Mac OS X). 
>      Any domain  will do, but "localnet" is traditional. Now when you
>      resolve "myhost" the resolver will attempt to look up 
>      "myhost.localnet" so you need to have dnsmasq reply to that name. 
>      The way to do that is to include the domain in each name on
>      /etc/hosts  and/or to use the --expand-hosts and --domain options.

So I suggest you post your `/etc/resolv.conf`, as well as the arguments you are feeding to dnsmasq when you start it.

Comment: here is my /etc/resolv.conf:

Comment: I added /etc/resolv.conf to the original post so it would look nicer instead of here.  I looked into what the arguments are that are getting fed to dnsmasq, but it is a bit convoluted by the surrounding /etc/init.d/dnsmasq script, or did you mean /etc/dnsmasq?

Answer (score 2):

Something I found: Everything appears to be configured ok, but dns name from /etc/hosts is not resolving. After adding/editing /etc/hosts (or any config file), don't forget to restart dnsmasq process to re-read the file. Dnsmasq imports these files on startup, it's not a live lookup.

Answer (score 1):

What does your /etc/resolv.conf look like? Look for domain or search elements.

Setup a .local domain for dnsmasq and then add that to your resolv.conf and it should work.

Try dig sun.local @localhost.

Answer (score 1):

I've just found what happens behind the scenes:
dnsmasq tries to expand `sun` to `sun.` when it reads /etc/hosts file.
If you try to resolve `sun.` it returns the correct result, but if you query it for `sun` it forwards the request to upstream DNS servers.

To work around this behaviour:

- add `local` to `/etc/resolv.conf`, e.g.:

> search local ec2.internal

- add `sun.local` to `/etc/hosts` or `/etc/dnsmasq.hosts`, e.g.:

> 10.79.114.99 sun sun.local

- restart dnsmasq

When a client queries for `sun` the DNS resolver will autoexpand the query to `sun.local` first and return the result from hosts file.

Answer (score -1):

dig, as well as host, and nslookup are specifically created to query dns servers. It will not look at /etc/hosts, and in fact will ignore /etc/nsswitch.conf

Anything using the gethostbyname call will however use /etc/nsswitch.conf

For example, ping should use /etc/hosts provided files is before dns in /etc/nsswitch.conf which it normally is.

Comment: I thought this too, but dnsmasq specifically serves dns names from /etc/hosts on the server.  It appears that if you configure everything correctly then dig to the server will actually end up giving you answers from /etc/hosts, bypassing nsswitch, etc.

Comment: Try running 'strace dig sun' and posting the results, that will let you know if dig is in fact using dnsmasq.

Also, a cop of your /etc/resolve.conf file would be helpful, specifically looking to see if domain is set.